# In a civil case, do both Plaintiff and Defendant have the same exhibit lettering?

Tags: small-claims-court

For instance, if the Plaintiff files a complaint and references "Exhibit A" and the Defendant files an answer denying the allegations of the complaint and also wants to reference some document/evidence, does the Defendant start labeling their documents with "Exhibit A" or do they start where the Plaintiff left off (i.e. "Exhibit B")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labeling is document-scoped. Each will start labeling their exhibits with "A".

If anyone needs to refer to exhibits from another document they will say "Document XXX, Exhibit A".